# unique id of variable (like spl_object_hash)

Tags: php

Is it possible to get unique id of scalar/array variable in PHP5.3
Something like object hash for objects. For example i have:

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3);
$b = &$a;
```

so unique id for variable $a and $b, has to be same, maybe derrived from memory pointer.
I didn't find any alternative function to [`spl_object_hash`](http://php.net/spl_object_hash).

Comment: PHP doesn't do memory pointers. At most you could do something like `md5(serialize($a))` to get a signature, but that wouldn't let you differentiate between two seaparate arrays that happen to have the same contents.

Comment: I think, that PHP has memory pointers internally in reference table. So i was looking for some IDs derrived from them. I can't use data hash. Two variables (where first is not reference of second) could have same value.

Comment: Yes, internally it does have standard C/C++ pointers, but they're not exposed to the script level.

Comment: Mind that PHP's copy on write might cause wrong rsults:  $a = $b still uses the same memorz location (same with function parameters etc.) So this would be quite misleading. Adding such a thing from a custom PHP extension is possible, but PHP doesn't offer a native way.

Comment: Ah, and another thought: Thanks to the way the engine handles temporary variables, constants and "compiled variables" the adress might not be globally unique fr more than the current function call

Answer (score 2):

small workaround:

```
function unique_var($var) {
    return md5(serialize($var));
}
```

Comment: Only problem with this is that it cannot distinguish between two distinct variables, with the same value, which I think is probably required here.

Comment: Not sure it needs to distinguish between distinct arrays. He said that the unique ID for `$a` and `$b` has to be the same; which it would be using Peter's technique.  But, of course, I could create another new array with the same data, and get the same hash, which might be what you mean.

Comment: Exactly, i need unique id, instead of data hash, because of the same value problem. I'm sorry, my answer was not so precise.